# what is the purpose of overriding hashcode in java object?

Tags: java, hashtable, hashcode

I know multiple object having same hashcode in java objects.It doesn't make any problem at all.So, What is the purpose of overriding hashcode in java...

In which situation it is advisable to do override the hashcode in java?

Comment: @RohitJain: I saw that, but it doesn't really talk about the *purpose*.

Comment: @JonSkeet. Yeah right, it's not really around the purpose. But somewhere deep down some answer, it's mentioned in a small statement. Still it will be useful for OP. :)

Answer (score 8):

> In which situation it is advisable to do override the hashcode in java?

When you override `equals`, basically. It means that collections which are hash-based (e.g. `HashMap`, `HashSet`) can very quickly find a set of *candidate* objects which will be equal to the one you're looking for (or trying to add, or whatever). If you have a large collection, you split it into buckets by hash code. When you're trying to look something up, you find the hash code of the object you've been passed, and look for objects with the same hash code within the relevant bucket. Then for each object with the *exact* same hash code, you call `equals` to see whether the two objects are *really* the same.

See the [Wikipedia article on hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for more information.

EDIT: A quick note on the choice of hash codes...

It's always *valid* to just override `hashCode` and return some constant (the same for every call) regardless of the contents of the object. However, at that point you lose all benefit of the hash code - basically a hash-based container will think that *any* instance of your type might be equal to any other one, so searching for one will consist of O(N) calls to `equals`.

On the other end of the scale, if you don't implement `hashCode` correctly and return a *different* value for calls to equal objects (or two calls on the same object twice) you won't be able to find the object when you search for it - the different hash codes will rule out equality so `equals` will never even be called.

Then there's the aspect of mutability - it's generally a bad idea for `equals` and `hashCode` to use mutable aspects of an object: if you mutate an object in a hash-changing way after you've inserted it into a hash-based collection, you won't be able to find it again because the hash at the time of insertion will no longer be correct.

Comment: I suggest pointing out the different consequences of inconsistency in each direction. Having two objects that are equal but have different hash codes can cause wrong answers from a hashed data structure. Having all elements use the same hash code will never cause a wrong answer, but will cause poor performance.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Good point. Will add an edit when I get some time. (May not be for a little while.)

Comment: @jonSkeet I am sorry... i am not clear... Could you explain little bit more for me?

Comment: @Saravanan: Not without more idea of what in particular you don't understand. Did you read the linked wikipedia article? Have you used hash tables before?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes i am used... am looking the wikipedia one more time...